# How to make a view as a url in templates.? (Python 3.6, Django 2.2)

Tags: django, django-templates

These are my code

```
#urls

urlpatterns += [
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
    path('products/', include('products.urls', namespace='products')),
    ]
```

This is app urls

```
# urls

app_name = 'products'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ProductHomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('details/', ProductView.as_view(), name='details'),

]
```

This is my view

```
#views

class ProductHomeView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        product_data = Product.objects.all()

        context = {
            'product': product_data,

        }
        return render(request, 'product_home.html', context)



class ProductView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        product_data = Product.objects.all()

        context = {
            'product': product_data,

        }
        return render(request, 'product.html', context)
```

this is my template

```
# template product_home.html

{% for product in product %}
    <h1>{{ product.tittle }}</h1>
    <p>{{ product.short_description }}</p>

    <button type="button"><a href="{% url 'products.details' %}">Explore More</a></button><br>

{% endfor %}
```

This is the error

## Error

django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'products.details' not found. 'products.details' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: It's "products:details", not "products.details".

Comment: It's working. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `.` instead of a `:`.

In this line:

`<button type="button"><a href="{% url 'products.details' %}">Explore More</a></button><br>`

You need to change `'products.details'` to `'products:details'`